# How to match parentheses in regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match parentheses in the following regular expression, but don't know how?

```
\w*\s*[\[\]]\s*\w*\s*(.)
```

The parentheses in the above expression are not being matched. How can I get it to match? I already tried escaping them but still it does't work.

Edit: Okay, I found out the reason the escaping did not work is related a different. So they do in fact work

Comment: Can you give sample inputs?

Comment: You may need to escape twice,

Comment: In regex you need to escape the parenthesis - so `\(`. But in a Java `String`, the backslash has special meaning, you need to escape that. You end up with `\\(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parenthesis in Java regular expressions do have special meaning - they represent regex group**, so that you can query only a subset of matched regular expression.

You need to escape it as `\\(` and `//)`